# hello world of Apache Airflow not working

Tags: airflow

I am learning Apache Airflow and trying to write hello world version of it.

I have setup up apache airflow version 2.0 with python version 3.8and below is code containing dag and task

```
import datetime
import logging

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


def greet_hello():
    logging.info("Hello World")


dag = DAG("FirstDag", start_date=datetime.datetime.now(),schedule_interval=None)

first_task = PythonOperator(python_callable=greet_hello , dag=dag , task_id="first-task")
```

I have configured apache airflow in the following way

1. pip install apache-airflow in venv
2. airflow create user ....
3. airflow db init
4. airflow webserver
5. airflow scheduler

I can see the Dag in the UI

[image]

But when I check the task instance details I see below message

"Task Instance State    Task is in the 'None' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run."

Even though the scheduler is running I am getting below message in UI

[image]

When I go to graph view  , and hover over first-task , it says not yet started. I am struggling to figure out what wrong I am going and how to resolve it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there are two issues here.

1. The DAG itself appears to be paused. You'll need to set it to `Active` in order for the task to be scheduled.
2. The scheduler alert is likely giving you slightly misleading information. Airflow involves multiple separate processes running concurrently. It uses a "heartbeat" to keep track of whether the scheduler process is alive. In other words, the scheduler is checking in with another airflow process on a periodic interval. If the scheduler hasn't made a heartbeat within a predetermined amount of time, Airflow isn't sure if the scheduler is still alive it puts up this error.

The reason this is misleading is that it could just mean that the scheduler is configured to heartbeat less frequently than airflow the "healthy" cutoff time interval. This often happens when using airflow locally. The default configuration is set up to minimize system resources, so the heartbeat can be infrequent.

This is straightforward to check.

1. Check to see what value airflow is using to determine if the scheduler has made a heartbeat recently enough.

```
$ airflow config get-value scheduler scheduler_health_check_threshold

30
```

On my machine, airflow considers the scheduler to be healthy if it has returned a heartbeat in the last 30 seconds.

2. Check the heart rate value. This is how often the scheduler checks in to, among other things, indicate that it's healthy.

```
$ airflow config get-value scheduler scheduler_heartbeat_sec

5
```

Here, airflow checks in every 5 seconds.

If `scheduler_heartbeat_sec` > `scheduler_health_check_threshold`, you'll see the  message you indicated. That doesn't mean that anything is broken, it just means that airflow is unsure whether the scheduler is alive.

3. To make sure the scheduler is running, check whatever terminal window you're using to run the scheduler. If it's outputting logs on regular intervals and you don't see any errors, it should be working properly.
4. To check the last time the scheduler made a heartbeat `http://localhost:8080/health` (or whatever port you're using locally). Don't worry about the `status` value, since that's generated with the same logic surrounding `heartbeat` and `heartrate`. But `latest_scheduler_heartbeat` will tell you when the scheduler most recently had a heartbeat.

Comment: Check the health of scheduler ...shows healthy and there is no error in there logs of scheduler

Comment: Did you do the other steps, including making sure your DAG is active? It also wouldn't hurt to stop and restart your scheduler.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue following the steps you mentioned.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Never use `datetime.datetime.now()` as the `start_date`. Please read https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date to understand why not.

The `start_date` should be as static as possible.

Secondly, as James suggested, make sure you `unpause` the DAG from the Webserver or set `is_paused_upon_creation` to `True` to the DAG object